# Strange granulated black triangles after texturing

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

Im rather new at Blender and i have a little issue when i render my model. As you can see in the next image:
[image: What are those granulated triangles?]

When i render my model after applying textures, only these two parts of the complete model (villager7_eyes and villager7_mouth) show strange granulated triangles and some of them are black. I've checked the normals and all of them are pointing outside the triangles, so what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for replying

Comment: Seems like double vertices are present (try to use `W` > *Remove doubles* in Edit mode with all selected), and probably these faces use flat shading (in Edit mode `W` > *Shade Smooth*).

Comment: I did that but it says "0 vertices removed" in the upper info box, and there aren't noticeable changes.

Comment: what you see is called Z-fighting. It occurs when you have orlapping/duplicated geometry. (more than one face on the same place)

Comment: I will check it out later, that answer seems the solution to my problem. If that's the case i will come back and mark it as solved. I searched before posting but i couldn't find that answer.

Comment: @cegaton I finally fixed it. As the face and the eyes were two different meshes they had duplicated geometry indeed. What i did was dissolving the faces on the body mesh and then the eyes' mesh didn't show up the granulated triangles. Don't know if it is the best fix, but i coulnd't do anything better i think. Now the head is a bit more "sunken" but i think it will work for what i want (printing this model in 3D)